# Как войти в БД. Mongo, зная адрес который начинается с mongodb://, пароль и прочее

Tags: mongodb

Есть файл со всеми конфигами. Как зайти в монгоатлас или прочее на нем?  Я имею ввиду про графический интерфейс.

Comment: mongodb://username:password@host:port

Comment: так мне с браузера зайти нужно

Comment: url образец такой же, только с логином и паролем. Мне бы зайти как в mongo atlas

Comment: Mongo Atlas и Монго-сервер - это несвязные аккаунты. Если вас интересует именно графический интерфейс при подключении к опред. базе, тогда можно использовать Mongo Compass.